# test for parameter containing only whitespace

Tags: bash

Is there a reliable, portable (i.e. works on /bin/bash on most systems) construct for testing whether a parameter contains only whitespace?

Is there a way to do this using shell builtins only (i.e. not calling out to sed, perl, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes pure bash way:

```
s="      "
[[ "$s" =~ ^[[:blank:]]+$ ]] && echo "containes only spaces"
```

OR

```
[[ "$s" =~ ^[[:space:]]+$ ]] && echo "containes only spaces"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if there are just one space, you can do it like this:

```
$ d=" "
$ [ "$d" == " " ] && echo "only space"
only space
$ d="  " <--- two spaces
$ [ "$d" == " " ] && echo "only space"
$
```